# how to update the array object using id and the props in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array object and I want to update the array object using id and props.

below is the structure of array object,

```
array object = [{columGrp:"All",deafultColumnName:"a",id:0},{columGrp:"ll",deafultColumnName:"ww",id:1},{columGrp:"oo",deafultColumnName:"qq",id:2},{columGrp:"qq",deafultColumnName:"ee",id:3}]
```

I have an editable table design and when a field changes I am passing field name, id, and changed value. based on that how can I update the object array.

```
const onChange=(props,value,id)=>{
   //code here
}
onChange("columGrp","qwerty",1);
 // result =>
 array object = [{columGrp:"All",deafultColumnName:"a",id:0},{columGrp:"qwerty",deafultColumnName:"ww",id:1},{columGrp:"oo",deafultColumnName:"qq",id:2},{columGrp:"qq",deafultColumnName:"ee",id:3}]
```

a help would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the object by id from your array of objects using the filter function. If the object exists, you then change the given property, passing the given value. Objects work by reference in javascript so any changes in the found object will affect your object inside your array too.

```js
const objectsArray = [{
  columGrp: "All",
  deafultColumnName: "a",
  id: 0
}, {
  columGrp: "ll",
  deafultColumnName: "ww",
  id: 1
}, {
  columGrp: "oo",
  deafultColumnName: "qq",
  id: 2
}, {
  columGrp: "qq",
  deafultColumnName: "ee",
  id: 3
}];

const onChange = (props, value, id) => {
  const obj = objectsArray.find(x => x.id === id);
  if (obj) {
    obj[props] = value;
  }
}

onChange("columGrp", "qwerty", 1);

console.log(objectsArray)
```

Comment: thanks for the try and your time :). but this returns only the changed element :(

Comment: @ThomasJames this way you firstly find the first object matching the id you provide and gives the value to the specific property you provide. Objects in javascript work by reference so the object inside your array has now changed.

Comment: @ThomasJames I just edited my answer. Let me know if you find it helpful or if there's something missing.

Comment: awesome thanks a lot it worked buddy :)